# Please help me understand unfamiliar struct syntax in C

Tags: c, struct

I've come across some C syntax that I've never seen before:

```
static struct {
    char *name;
    void (*f)(int a, int b, int c);
} commands[] = {
    { "cmd1", func1 },
    { "cmd2", func2 },
    { "cmd3", func3 },
};
```

This pertains to a command parser that matches a user input command to one of the respective functions like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    if (strcmp(args[0], commands[i].name) == 0) {
        (commands[i].f)(a, b, c);
        return;
    }
}
```

I can't even search google for help because I don't know what this sort of structure is called, and it seems somewhat esoteric.

What I want to do is create more of these structs, then put the loop into a separate function and generalize it, so that I can pass the function different structs depending on certain conditions. However I can't figure out how to assign the structs to a variable and pass them to a function.

Comment: This syntax defines array of `struct`s named `commands` and initialises it

Comment: I think it's called an "anounymous struct" because it's being used as a nameless type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to do is create more of these structs, then put the loop into a separate function and generalize it

Then you probably want to give a name (tag) to the struct, like this:

```
struct command {
    const char *name; // notice the `const', by the way!
    void (*f)(int a, int b, int c);
};
```

and isolate the type definition and the variable declaration:

```
struct command commands[] = {
    { "cmd1", func1 },
    { "cmd2", func2 },
    { "cmd3", func3 },
};
```

The trick is that the `struct` keyword creates a type immediately (as soon as the closing brace in the structure definition is encountered), so you don't **have to** have a separate `struct` declaration **and** the definition of a variable of that struct type, these can be merged -- that's what the code you posted does.

Comment: Ahh this makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The member `void (*f)(int a, int b, int c);` is a pointer to a function that returns `void` and takes 3 `int` arguments.

Note that you cannot create any other variables of this type because the structure has no tag.  You also can't pass this structure to any other function for the same reason.

```
typedef struct Command
{
    char *name;
    void (*f)(int a, int b, int c);
} Command;

static Command commands[] =
{
    { "cmd1", func1 },
    { "cmd2", func2 },
    { "cmd3", func3 },
};
```

The type `Command` or `struct Command` can now be used elsewhere if the type definition is placed in a suitable location (at file scope, or in a header).